# Login before scenario with Behat and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, behat

First of all I've read [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108001/behat-authenticate-symfony2-user) and [this other approach (blog post)](http://www.robinvdvleuten.nl/blog/handle-authenticated-users-in-behat-mink/).

This is my `behat.yml`:

```
default:
    suites:
        users:
            contexts:
                - DoctrineFixturesContext
                - FeatureContext
                - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
                - Sanpi\Behatch\Context\RestContext
                - Sanpi\Behatch\Context\JsonContext
            paths: [%paths.base%/features/users]
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: 
            kernel:
                env: "test"
                debug: "true"
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: ''
            sessions:
                default:
                    symfony2: ~
        Sanpi\Behatch\Extension: ~
```

Now what I want is to reproduce the behavior of a user, which is:

- User logs in **once**
- Requests have then an `Authorization` header with the token

The easiest way I've found is to simply mimic the user behavior:

```
class FeatureContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    private $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request; 
    }

    /**
     * @BeforeScenario @Login
     */
    public function login() 
    {
        $d = $this->request->send('POST', '/login_check', ['_username' => 'test', '_password' => 'test']);
        $data = json_decode($d->getContent());
        $this->request->setHttpHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '.$data->token);
    }
}
```

The user is previously loaded through fixtures. This works well except that the `Authorization` header is not kept through the next steps:

```
Feature: Get my availables menus
  @Login
  Scenario: Get my menus
    When I send a "GET" request to "/api/menus"
    Then the response status code should be 200
```

The response is 401.

Why is the Authorization header not kept through the scenario? How may I achieve this simple task?

Answer (score 2):

As you can read [here](https://github.com/Behatch/contexts/issues/110), following [here](https://github.com/Behatch/contexts/issues/119), the Behatch/RestContext is quite useful (a lot of shortcuts and handful methods) but it's quite messy with the symfony2 integration.

As @stof says in [this comment](https://github.com/Behatch/contexts/pull/75#issuecomment-44983348):

> The rest-context is a huge mistake altogether. Mink is not a REST client (browsers are not REST clients either). There is no point using the Mink driver to perform the REST API calls. It is the wrong tool for the job.

Longo story short: it seems that the request headers you set are not passed with the request.

Having said that, you can try with this workaround:

```
Feature: Get my availables menus
  @Login
  Scenario: Get my menus
    # note the change in the following line
    # When I send a "GET" request to "/api/menus"
    When I am on "/api/menus"
    Then the response status code should be 200
```

Basically, using the *When I am on...* you are using the MinkContext and the request headers are properly passed with the request.

Of course I know this is not the perfect solution (eg: how to handle POST request??) but at least the specific test you described should pass.

Let me know. Ciao

Comment: Is there no alternative to mink that does not use a browser? Behat syntax is nice to write tests, I could also [find another way](https://twitter.com/s0yuka/status/452045934353211392?lang=en) to test my api.

Comment: The problem is not Mink. The "problems" are the Behatch Extensions (especially related to the request headers stuff), that, anyway, i also use a lot since they are really handy. As I wrote, You can still use the gherkin language (Behat syntax)...

Comment: I surely understand that my issue here is that headers are not persistent through the scenario. From what you say, doing what I though I could do is not possible, or I'd have to avoid POST requests. 
I think that I'll write my api tests using Gerkin with nodejs... Less headache.

Comment: hi @soyuka, i was looking to my related opened questions/answer. I think you can mark the answer as the "good" one, do you?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the Authorization header not kept through the scenario? How may I achieve this simple task?

I would first of all what is this `Request` object that you're injecting in your context? If your idea is to inject the request object that will be used in your Symfony application, then that won't work as the object [will be created by the front controller](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/app.php#L27) when Mink will "visit the page".

Moreover, I would recommend to use directly the Symfony's kernel in your context files to send requests to your application. With the Symfony2Extension of Behat, you can *instanciate* your `FeatureContext` with the kernel by mentioning the service you want to inject in the `behat.yml` file:

```
default:
    suites:
        users:
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext:
                      - @kernel
```

Then, you can create request objects manually and send them to the Symfony kernel. Here's an example of sending the almost the same `POST` request than in your example:

```
class FeatureContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    private $kernel;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel; 
    }

    /**
     * @What user :username is authenticating itself with :password 
     */
    public function userIsAuthenticatingItselfWith($username, $password) 
    {
        $response = $this->kernel->handle(Request::create(
            '/login_check',
            'POST',
            [],
            [],
            [],
            [
                'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ],
            http_build_query([
                '_username' => $username,
                '_password' => $password,
            ])
        ));

        // Do whatever you want with the `$response` object to check that
        // the user is successfully authenticated for instance..
    }
}
```

But you can see that I changed the method signature and actually didn't store the token or anything else: this is intended to actually test this authentication, but not as a *Given* step.

The Symfony authentication system contains a `TokenStorage` object that stores the current authentication token. So if you want to "fake" an authentication, you can simply set a token in the object, with a step definition that will probably look like that:

```
class SecurityContext implements Context
{
    /**
     * @var TokenStorageInterface
     */
    private $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
     */
    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @Given I am authenticated as :username
     */
    public function iAmAuthenticated()
    {
        $token = new YourTokenClass(['ROLE_USER']);
        $token->setUser(new YouUserClass($username));

        $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
    }
}
```

And then, instead of scenario hooks, you can simply use the `Given I am authenticated as :username` in your scenario or even with the [`Background`s](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html#backgrounds).

Comment: Looks interesting! I should try this one

Comment: Can I modify Behat request in this way? I need to attach query parameters on every request.